# What is wrong in the following query?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have tried this query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `references`
 WHERE
 (`continent_id` IN (2,8) AND `country_id`IN (18) )
   OR `continent_id` IN (2,8)
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

here what I am trying to do is select those records with either both **country & continent id** or only **continent id** but above query always resulting the records with  **continent id** only i.e ( OR `continent_id` IN (2,8) being always **true**)

Any idea what is going wrong in this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have **where (a AND b) OR a**
which is the same as **where a**

What exactly are you trying to do - give an example please.

Comment: Can you show a sample data and the resulting output of the query?

Comment: @DavidC I think you right , any idea how to avoid passing continent_id in the second condition i.e in the `OR`

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong beacuse if your first condition is OK then the second is surely right. And then it is OR so only the second condition works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `references` WHERE `continent_id` IN (2,8) OR `country_id`IN (18)
```